# Struts 2.5.2 - <s:div> tag has disappeared

Tags: struts2

I have just upgraded to 2.5.2 and now my jsp pages are failing with

> **org.apache.jasper.JasperException:**
>   /WEB-INF/content/diagnostics/nanocom-list-as-is-history.jsp (line: 96,
>   column: 6) No tag "div" defined in tag library imported with prefix
>   "s"

It's only the **`<s:div>`** tag that is causing a problem, all the other tags are behaving as expected. I still see the **`<s:div>`** tag is covered in the Struts 2 Tag Reference and It is not mentioned in the release notes that this tag is removed.

Edited to clarify as requested;

After upgrading from Struts 2.3.16.1 any jsp page that contains the  tag fails to display and the exception listed above is thrown.

Comment: Isn't the div tag part of the deprecated Dojo tags? What version did you update from? The long-deprecated Dojo plugin was finally completely removed in Struts 2.5.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Dave Newton - according to the Struts2 Tag Reference sx:div is the Dojo tag.

Comment: @Roman C -  After upgrading from Struts 2.3.16.1 any jsp page that contains the <s:div> tag fails to display and the exception listed is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

`<s:div>` tag was deprecated (it was related to DOJO plugin) and was removed in Struts 2.5 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?version=12324447&projectId=12311041
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4614